# Get the start and end date of all the weeks for a given month in python exclusive of other months dates

Tags: python, calendar

I need to get the start and end dates of all the weeks for a given month in python.

**Sample Input Dec 2018**

**Possible outputs**

01-12-2018

02-12-2018 - 08-12-2018

09-12-2018 - 15-12-2018

16-12-2018 - 22-12-2018

23-12-2018 - 29-12-2018

30-12-2018 - 31-12-2018

I used calendar module as follows,

```
obj_cal= calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=6)
[x for x in cal.monthdatescalendar(2018, 12)]
```

But this includes dates from 2018 Nov as well as from 2019 Jan

How to get exclusive of other month dates.

**NB: Question edited**

Comment: So, what code do you have so far?

Comment: You might to check out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
import calendar
from datetime import timedelta

# sunday is the first day of the week
# set 0 for monday
firstweekday = 6

def weeks_in_month(year, month):
    c = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday)
    for weekstart in filter(lambda d: d.weekday() == firstweekday, c.itermonthdates(year, month)):
        weekend = weekstart + timedelta(6)
        yield (weekstart, weekend)


for weekstart, weekend in weeks_in_month(2018, 12):
    print(weekstart, '-', weekend)
```

Output:

```
2018-11-25 - 2018-12-01
2018-12-02 - 2018-12-08
2018-12-09 - 2018-12-15
2018-12-16 - 2018-12-22
2018-12-23 - 2018-12-29
2018-12-30 - 2019-01-05
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime    
>>> import calendar
>>> cld=calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=0)
>>> for end_day in cld.itermonthdates(2018,12):
...     if end_day.weekday()==5:
...         start_day=end_day-datetime.timedelta(6)
...         print('{} - {}'.format(start_day.isoformat(),end_day.isoformat()))
... 
2018-11-25 - 2018-12-01
2018-12-02 - 2018-12-08
2018-12-09 - 2018-12-15
2018-12-16 - 2018-12-22
2018-12-23 - 2018-12-29
2018-12-30 - 2019-01-05
```